# What difference between columnar and wide column databases?

Tags: nosql, rdbms

What difference between **columnar** database (AWS Redshift, Azure Synapse, GCP Bigquery, Snowflake) and **wide column** database (AWS Keyspaces, Azure CosmosDB, GCP Bigtable, Hbase, Cassandra)?

What I understand so far:

- Columnar databases are SQL (ACID transactions compliant)
- And wide column databases are NoSQL (Scalability, etc)
- Columnar databases (AWS Redshift, Azure Synapse, GCP Bigquery, Snowflake) are warehouses
- And wide column databases (AWS Keyspaces, Azure CosmosDB, GCP Bigtable, Hbase, Cassandra) are just "pure" databases

Answer (score 4):

Wide column stores and column-oriented database systems store their data differently:

- Column-oriented database systems store the data using a column-oriented data layout. Values for the same column are stored contiguously on disk.
- Wide column stores group columns into column families (which usually have data of the same data type). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide-column_store):

> Within a given column family, all data is stored in a row-by-row
> fashion, such that the columns for a given row are stored together,
> rather than each column being stored separately.

Data belonging to the same key is stored together. It uses multi-dimensional mapping to reference data by column, row and timestamp. (Timestamp, because new versions of the value in the cell/field are added rather than overwriting the previous value.)

> Columnar databases (AWS Redshift, Azure Synapse, GCP Bigquery, Snowflake) are warehouses

Maybe it is more correct to say that columnar database systems are well suited for data warehouses.

ScyllaDB is another wide column store worth mentioning in addition to the ones you already listed.

See also:

- The [Wide-column Database](https://db-engines.com/en/article/Wide+Column+Stores) article in the db-engines.com Encyclopedia.
- The [Wide-column Database](https://www.scylladb.com/glossary/wide-column-database/) article on the ScyllaDB website.

Comment: ScyllaDB is the same as Casandra since it's based on it...

Comment: @AlexisWilke I wouldn't say it's the same since it's completely rewritten in C++ while Cassandra is written in Java. That said, it is deliberately designed to be compatible with Cassandra by supporting CQL,  Cassandra's query language, the same protocols and SSTable file format. But it also has other features not found in Cassandra. So I would consider ScyllaDB to be its own thing.